# What are these two holes on the forward fuselage of a Boeing 747?

Tags: boeing-747, fuselage

Does anyone know what are the two holes are on the Boeing 747, on the left forward part of the fuselage?

[image]
<sub>Source: [airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/EVA-Air-Cargo/Boeing-747-45EF-SCD/2679144/L)</sub>

I guess the right hole is the E/E compartment smoke override valve, is that correct?

Another hole under the belly just before pack inlet:

[image]

What is the function or name of this one?

Answer (score 5):

The forward opening is the ***forward outflow valve*** or ***forward overboard valve*** (depending on reference consulted) which opens automatically if airflow in the forward compartment is low. It is independent from the two large *aft outflow valves* at the lower aft hull used for pressurization.

The second valve is the ***smoke override valve*** used in case there is smoke sensed in the the E&E compartment. Basically you try to get rid of the smoke by dumping it overboard. The second function is in case the fans used for ventilation of the E&E compartment fail. Then this valve is opened as well and the differential pressure ventilates the E&E compartment in reverse flow direction. The duct who was supplying the air is now sucking it out of the compartment.

The opening close to the pack inlet on the R/H side is the ***ground exhaust valve*** used to dump the air used for E&E cooling on ground overboard in case the temperature is high. This valve is always closed in flight.

Reference:

- *Boeing 747-400 System Schematic Manual*, chapter 21, valves V462 (forward overboard valve), V447 (ground exhaust valve), V448 (smoke override valve)
- internal documentation provided by employer of the author

Comment: @mins unfortunately I'm unable to share the documentation I have as it is Boeing proprietary or my employer proprietary. If you can get hold of the _Boeing 747-400 System Schematic Manual_ Chapter 21 have a look on schematic 21-58-00 sheet 1. You are interested in the valves V447 & V448.

Comment: Chris: Your edits look perfect to me. Great answer!

Answer (score -3):

The forward one is exhaust for E&E cooling. The aft one probably is dirt on the camera lens. You can see from the close up that it is a miss shaped circle.

Comment: It's not on the camera. See http://www.jetphotos.net/photo/8445641 http://www.jetphotos.net/photo/8433213 and http://www.jetphotos.net/photo/8402175

Comment: Dirt on cameras is always very out of focus in any image. It produces vague blobs that are slightly darker than whatever's in the image, not sharply defined black marks.

Comment: Simply not true. Please check your facts before posting.